# OpenCV with Python wont exit properly when using detectMultiScale on CascadeClassifier

Tags: python, opencv

I am experimenting with OpenCV and facial recognition. It has been working without any issuess until lately when it stopped exiting my script and I am forced to close the commandprompt. After some debugging I have located the culprit to be this line. The program exits properly if I remove this line but then I dont have the option to detect faces :(

```
faces = FACE_CLASSIFIER.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=SCALE_FACTOR, minNeighbors=MIN_NEIGHBORS)
```

I have also experimented using this code before and after the destroy windows command but it had no effect

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I found this information in the opencv documentation

> When the cascade is not needed anymore, release it using
>   cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade(&cascade).

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html

I think this might be the proper solution but I haven't been able to find a method that would allow me to do this.

**Sampe code**

I start with from commandline using

```
python face.py
```

face.py

```
import cv2

FACE_CLASSIFIER = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
SCALE_FACTOR = 1.5
MIN_NEIGHBORS = 5

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # If this line is removed the program exits properly 
    faces = FACE_CLASSIFIER.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=SCALE_FACTOR, minNeighbors=MIN_NEIGHBORS)

    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**System information**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836]

pip3 list
Package               Version
--------------------- --------
numpy                 1.18.5
opencv-contrib-python 3.4.9.33
pip                   20.1.1
setuptools            41.2.0

python --version
Python 3.7.7
```

Comment: do you get any error message when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe?

Comment: link shows parameter `cascade` with text `OpenCV 1.x API only` - so probably  `cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade` is needed only for `OpenCV 1.x`

Comment: code works correctly on LInux Mint, Python 3.7.7, OpenCV 4.2.0. `print(cv2.__version__)`. Maybe update modules to the newest versions - `pip install --upgrade opencv-python opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: I only get a warning **'[ WARN:1] global
C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp
    > (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback**

I discoved that i can be remove if I set this Enviroment variable. It unfortunately has not effect to the program exiting properly. **SET OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF=0**

I have tried varios version of opencv-contrib-python to no avail and I run the application from CMD

Comment: A quick sidenote. Whenever my program hangs I needed to reboot the application if I want to change the opencv-contrib-python package as one of the files is locked. Therefore the testing of different opencv-contrib-python packages requires a reboot. I also tried to run the application from a virtual-env to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is related to opencv-contrib-python package. I have tried the following packages and they all work.

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.3.18
```

These versions all introduce this warning but it still works.

```
[ WARN:1] terminating async callback

pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.4.19
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.5.20
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.6.27
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.7.28
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.8.29
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.0.0.21
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.0.1.23
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.0.1.24
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25
```

These version all introduce this warning but it still works.

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.1.26
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.2.30
```

And these versions fail to run the application with clean exit.

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.9.31
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.9.33
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.32
```

Comment: maybe you should send this to opencv author on [issue tracker](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues)

Comment: or maybe send to author of opencv-python - https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python. OR maybe you already find this problem on his page in `issues`.

Comment: Thank you for the information on how to create an issue. I have added an issue on opencv-python project here. [https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/339](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/339)

Comment: The issue is related to the OpenCV MSMF backend, see this issue at OpenCV repository: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13255

Comment: My previous comment was related to the `terminating async callback` error. About the crash you should open issue to the OpenCV repository. It seems to be a bug which has been introduced in the latest versions of OpenCV.

Comment: I have created an issue at OpenCV https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17495